# Pass argument to a static constructor in Java?

Tags: java, static, constructor, static-constructor

I'm trying to initialize a static class, with an argument, and then run some more static code in that class.
I'm aware of the `static` block, but it seems it can't take any arguments.
Is there a way to pass arguments to a static constructor?
If not, what is the recommended technique to initialize a Static class using an argument?

**Edit:**
A static class to my understanding is a class which cannot be instantiated (in c# they're called static classes, if Java has a different term for them, sorry for not being aware of it) - it's accessed through it's class name rather than an object name.

What I'm trying to achieve (very simplified) is a class which receives a dictionary as String, parses it, and has methods manipulate it like `GetRandomEntry`.

Here's an elaborated snippet of my code:

```
public class QuestionsRepository {  
private static Map<String,String[]> easyDefinitions = new HashMap<String,String[]>();  

//...  

static 
    {  
    // need to receive and parse dictionary here    
    }  
//...
```

Taking the relevant parts of a code snippet is never easy, hope i have chosen wisely (:
Another detail that may be relevant - I'm a c# programmer, usually. Just Started learning Java lately.

Thanks.

Comment: This is heading in the wrong direction.  Any particular reason you cannot just use a normal constructor in a non-static class?

Comment: A static class that maintains state is like a singleton, which to me is a euphemism for a global variable. You should have an object that instantiates and maintains it instead of creating an object that anyone can access

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you would need to initialize the static fields of the class according to some input. You can do it in the following way by calling the static method of another class:

```
class ClassToInitialize {
    static {
        staticField = ParamPassClass.getParameter();
    }

    private static String staticField;

    ClassToInitialize() {
        System.out.println("This is the parameter: " + staticField);
    }

}

class ParamPassClass {
    private static String parameter;
    static String getParameter() {
        return parameter;
    }

    static void setParameter(String parameter) {
        ParamPassClass.parameter = parameter;
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ParamPassClass.setParameter("Test param");
        new ClassToInitialize();
    }
}
```

Comment: So I'll have a class just for holding the parameter? That sounds clever but a bit awkward. On the other hand, if that's the only way to go.. (?)

Comment: ..And more importantly - is it guaranteed that the static block at ClassToInitialize will run after SetParameter?

Comment: It doesn't mean that you need to keep an Object just to hold the parameter. It is just like, you can call a `static` method directly to pass the value, almost same as passing parameter. Also, it is possible to create an Object inside the static block and get the parameter value as required. Depends on your use and design.

Comment: Seems to cleaner to create a `static init` method instead that you can call whenever you want instead of the extra class. Even though using a stateful singleton is bad design.

Answer (score 3):

Java doesn't have static constructors. It only has static initializers and static initializers do not take any arguments. It is executed when the class is first loaded, and there is no way to call it yourself.

You either need to use actual objects, or add some way of configuring the class (eg through a static method).

Answer (score 1):

you should mention the member class with a static qualifier, otherwise there is no such a thing as a static class
[Here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/1999-08/01-qa-static2.html) you can find the explanation of using the word 'static' in this context.

Now you should just call its constructor and pass all the arguments you want, 
the only restriction that you have on a static member class is that it can't refer the non-static fields of its outer class, it resembles a static methods on class that can't refer the non-static fields of class.

I didn't understand why do you mention a static  initialization  block here, could you please clarify a little? 
Be aware also that in java there is no such a thing as static constructor....

Hope this helps

Comment: you mean that a class without a static modifier, and a constructor also without a static modifier, are both static in Java by default? (edited the question btw, to make it a clearer)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a static method `public static void setUp(Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2...)` which sets up all your `static` fields and invoke it when your program starts.

You have to make sure this method will be called only once [or only when you want to reset these fields]

Comment: But how will I make sure that method runs BEFORE my other static code?  Sorry for the delay, but please refer to my edit. Thanks (:

Comment: @ORenA: you can add a privage flag, which will be initalized to `false` in a static block, and will be set to `true` when `setUp()` is activated. Every method will have to check the flag and throw an `IllegalStateException` if it is false. I agree this solution is not the best one, is is just a rough thaught on how you can initialize with parameters...

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to pass arguments directly to the static initializes ([JLS:static initializers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#39245)).

It would be nice if you could share more information about your goals.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an enum to initialize a singleton with a string parameter like this

```
import java.util.*;
class Data {
    static Map<String,String[]> easyDefinitions = new HashMap<String,String[]>();  
}
public enum QuestionsRepository
{
    repository("primary=red,green,blue;secondary=cyan,yellow,magenta"); 
    QuestionsRepository(String dictionary) {
        String[] rules = dictionary.split(";");
        for (String rule:rules) {
            String[] keyValuePair = rule.split("=",2);
            Data.easyDefinitions.put(keyValuePair[0],keyValuePair[1].split(","));
        }
    }
}
```